# Power Automate - Changing the button text in the Start and Wait for Approval action email?

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

I have a email reminder flow with approval set up that pulls in information from a SharePoint list.

Is it possible to change the button text in the `Start and Wait for Approval` action email?

I'd like to change the text

**From:**

Approve >

Reject >

**To:**

Review Completed >

Reject >

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use custom responses like this blog mentioned:https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/introducing-custom-response-options-for-approvals/